# error - "need a single repository as an argument"

Tags: apt, repository

I am trying to set up a stable repository and getting an error -

```
need a single repository as an argument
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with this statement:

```
sudo add-apt-repository \ deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \ $(lsb_release -cs) \ stable
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are after this, actually:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
```

The quotes make the entire string you were trying to add be treated as a single argument.  This way you don't need to mess with escaping spaces (which your command didn't actually do properly which is why it all failed and gave you errors).

Note that you will still need to download the GPG key in use for the repository, as `add-apt-repository` is incapable of doing that for straight strings like you're adding here.